# Jquery: changing text inside a button when toggle 'show'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a toggle button to show and hide a div, but I'd like the text inside the button to change from 'Show Content' to "Hide Content' as you toggle 'show' on the #content div. This is a little over my head as I'm still learning jQuery. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**: I've discovered since I have many posts on a single page, and the code is repeated in all posts, when I click the button to show content on one post it shows the content on all the posts. How can this be remedied?

HTML

```
<div class="post-content">
  <button id='content-button'>Show Content</button>
  <div id='content'>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS
    #content
    {
        display:none;
    }

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/8/

Comment: To stop your code being applied to all other divs with same id use .stopPropagation()

Comment: @MarsOne thank you, where would I add that code in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/5/

Comment: inside the .click function. event.stopPropagation();http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/14/

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I click "Show Content" only the content of the specific post is shown, however, every button changes to "Hide Content" and can be used to control the hiding of the content of the initial post

Comment: Try and use the function i wrote for you in my answer. event.target will only target the clicked button.

Comment: I did, I copy and pasted the fiddle hehe. For example: I have 2 posts, if I click 'show content' on post #1, the button on post #2 changes to 'hide content'. And if I click 'show content' on post #2 it reveals the content on post #1 and changes the button to 'hide content'

Comment: would there be a way to change the code so it only targets the #content inside the parent div of the #content-button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61669/discussion-between-marsone-and-trying-hal9000).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {
        $('#content').is(":visible") ? $(this).text("Show Content") : $(this).text("Hide Content");
        jQuery('#content').toggle();
    });
});
```

Check the visibility of the div using `is(":visible")`, then change the text

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/5/)

**Edit**

```
jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next().is(":visible") ? $(this).text("Show Content") : $(this).text("Hide Content");
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I like this solution. But I've discovered a problem with my code where, since it is repeated in many posts on the same page, clicking one 'Show Content" button will reveal the content on all posts due to .content being present in all posts. How could this be modified to select only the .content in the parent div of the .content-button? I've edited my post above to show the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep when button is clicked and change text:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
        if (i == 0) {
            $(this).text("Hide Content");
            i = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show Content");
            i = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply code (sorry for the slide effect, but perhaps you are interested in this too):

```
JQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {    
  JQuery("#content").slideToggle("slow",function(){
    if (JQuery("#content").css("display")=="none"){ 
      JQuery(this).text("Show Content");
    } else {
      JQuery(this).text("Hide Content");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {        

        if(jQuery('#content').is(":hidden")){
            jQuery(this).text("Hide Content");
            jQuery('#content').show();
          }
        else{
             jQuery(this).text("Show Content");
             jQuery('#content').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text` to change text of button

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
////////////////////////////code to change text
        if($('#content-button').text()=="Show Content")
        {
         $('#content-button').text('hide content');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#content-button').text('show content');

        }
       //////////////////////////// 

});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/11/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function (event) {
        jQuery('#content').toggle('show', function () {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {

                $('#content-button').text("Show Content");
            } else {
                $('#content-button').text("Hide Content");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syctdh46/12/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy poda panii ..i know who u are

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are similar here.

Why not innovate and add a custom function here.

```
$.fn.toggleText = function(t1, t2){
  if (this.text() == t1) this.text(t2);
  else                   this.text(t1);
  return this;
};
```

And then just edit you code to use the function. So you can use this function anywhere else in your code. Simplifies thing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#content-button').live('click', function(event) {  
         $(event.target).toggleText('Show Content', 'Hide Content');  //Add this line          
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```